# Block Artifact Grid of an Image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

I have been reading [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.08484.pdf) paper where they have used Error Level Analysis (ELA) and Block Artifact Grid (BAG).

I have found a way to do the ELA using `skimage` from [here](https://github.com/agusgun/FakeImageDetector/blob/master/fake-image-detection.ipynb)

I want a final output of the BAG part showed in the diagram below [***Look at the BAG output specifically***] -
[image]

But I haven't found a single implementation of BAG in python:

> - Divide the image into 8 × 8 blocks. Take the DCT of the blocks (using an 8 × 8 DCT matrix and matrix multiply).
> - Make a histogram of the color-quantized DCT values for each of the 64 locations of the blocks (where the number of blocks and the number
>   of values in each histogram is equal to the number that can fit into
>   the image).
> - Take the Fast-Fourier Transform (FFT) of the histogram of each of the 64 frequencies to get the periodicity and then power spectrum to
>   get peaks.
> - Calculate the number of local minimums of the extrema. This is the estimated Q value.
> - Get a Q estimate for at least 32 Q values, and use it to calculate the block artifact (error in the Q value) for each image block. Output
>   an error map of the image.

**What I have tried**

I can try and figure out individual pieces like taking DCT, calculating FFT but unable to put everything together, especially `Q estimate for at least 32 Q values`, which is not making sense to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you can't "find a code", you have to write it. you'd benefit from having a paper that explains this "algorithm" and perhaps even provides a reference implementation. you have a paper, follow its references. the author didn't come up with "BAG".

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz thanks for your suggestion, but if you read the question, I _have_ tried implementing it on my own, I am not asking you to do my homework. I have also specified precisely where I am stuck. If you want to know what I have done so far, ask and I will edit my question, didn't want to clutter it with ~50 odd LOC I have come up with so far

Comment: You should try to contact the authors of the paper and ask them which implementation of BAG they have used. There is [code](https://github.com/IPOL-Fork/jpeg-god) for an [NFA/"A Contrario" based method](https://www.ipol.im/pub/art/2020/283/) for BAG analysis on the net. But that is probably not what you are looking for?

Comment: Maybe this might help you: https://github.com/matloff/imagefraud which contains code for BAG localization. (NOTE: I haven't tried it myself.)